# Cannot set breakpoints in scala editor by using eclipse scala IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala, ide, breakpoints

eclipse: 2019-12(4.14.0)
scala ide: 4.7.1
In scala source editor I cannot set breakpoint(using "Toggle Breakpoint", nothing happened), otherwise everything is ok in java editor.

Comment: Please, provide screenshot with your IDE, code and more context, so community can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Unhandled event loop exception

Comment: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expecting non-static method org.scalaide.ui.internal.editor.ScalaToggleBreakpointAdapter.getTextEditor(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPart;)Lorg/eclipse/ui/texteditor/ITextEditor;

Comment: at org.scalaide.ui.internal.editor.ScalaToggleBreakpointAdapter.protected$getTextEditor(ScalaToggleBreakpointAdapter.scala:49)

Comment: Please, update the question with details, don’t post them in comments section. Also stack trace don’t tell much, as I asked before, please provide the code which you want to debug with screenshot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade eclipse to version oxygen, problem solved!

Comment: this does not solve the problem, it's a workaround. Other plugins need the latest eclipse version. If I have to use different eclipse versions for different plugins, I simply could use intelliJ. I'm using eclipse because I could use one IDE for every project.